# jQuery and IE, not behaving at all

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

**Solution**

```
var options = { opacity: opacity }; //Many thanks to David Higgins for his help
var direction;
if(id == "chat") { 
    direction = {right: dir + amt, top: dir + amt };
} else if(id == "rplayed") { 
    direction = {left: dir + amt, top: dir + amt };
} else if(id == "info") { 
    direction = {right: dir + amt, bottom: dir + amt };
} else if(id == "player") { 
    direction = {left: dir + amt, bottom: dir + amt };
}
$.extend(options, direction);
$(wid).animate(options, 200);
```

**Question**

I've been working on a website that is very jQuery intensive in Chrome and Firefox. It's now come to the stage where one opens it in IE see how IE treating the website.

I've gone through the jQuery stuff and I really can't see what is wrong with anything I have written and IE just gives the error "Invalid arguament - line 142 - jquery.js" (the actual jQuery source file).

On the website jQuery has two main purposes, updating elements with Ajax and JSON and moving elements around (hiding/showing & sliding) to create a window'd interface).

The website is at *deadlink* and the JS is in *deadlink*

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my jQuery code? I have no idea where to start, I'm not expecting you to fix it just point me in the right direction and give me an idea of what's going on!

If you want to see what the website is supposed to do open it in FF or Chrome!

Many Thanks,

Comment: Don't have time to go through your code, I would suggest you to debug with Visual Studio. Turn on debugging mode in IE and see when/what causes the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that your code around line 102 of main.js:

```
$(wid).animate({
  opacity: opacity,
  left: left,
  top: top,
  bottom: bottom,
  right: right
}, 200);
```

Is passing 'undefined' as a value for 'top'.

My suggestion,

the code above it ... should do something more like this:

```
var options = { opacity: opacity };
if(id == "chat") {
  jQuery.extend({right: dir + amt, top: dir + amt }, options);
} else if(id == "rplayed") {
  jQuery.extend({left: dir + amt, top: dir + amt}, options);
} // snipped - you get the point
$(wid).animate(options, 200);
```

I haven't tested the whole jQuery.extend() call ... but this should solve your invalid parameter problem - IE does not like setting invalid values to CSS properties (this includes 'null', 'undefined', alpha when numeric was expected, '0' when 'none' was expected, etc). FF, Chrome and Safari all handle this gracefully ... by just ignoring the CSS value (and in this case, it was omitting the value for you - causing the render to look right).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awsome! May I ask how you found the line? (so I don't have to get someone else to do it for me in the future)

Edit: Going to test now!

Comment: I used IE8, and when it said the error occurred and prompted me to debug I chose a new copy of Visual Studio 2008 and walked back through the call stack until I found your local function call - evaluated the values being passed to the jQuery function and found 'undefined'.  Was really a 10 second thing - but I've been debugging JS for a long time ... second nature to me.  VS 2008 Express edition should suffice for this ... or the Javascript Debugger as well - I prefer VS 2008 though as I use it for my everyday coding needs.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid I don't have the time to comb through the source, but if your stuck and you don't have it already, try stepping through the js with [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite) to track down the issue.